# alternative for GZIPSTREAM in WP8

Tags: windows-phone-8, gzipstream

I'm working on a WP8 application that uses a Webservice that is shared with a WP6 application
This webservice uses GZipStream to compress the communicated answers.

Now it seems that WP8 doesn't support this way of compression

Does someone know how i still can decompress and compress the returned stream?

I've been searching the Net for 2 days now and I've found no answer to this problem.

The only way I see now is to remove the compression on the 2 sides in production and that Is not my ittention

(sorry for my english)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Morten's [SharpGIS.GZipWebClient](http://nuget.org/packages/SharpGIS.GZipWebClient) to make GZip WebRequests on WP7/WP8. Read more about it [here](http://www.sharpgis.net/post/2011/08/28/GZIP-Compressed-Web-Requests-in-WP7-Take-2.aspx).

```cs
WebRequest.RegisterPrefix("http://", SharpGIS.WebRequestCreator.GZip);
WebRequest.RegisterPrefix("https://", SharpGIS.WebRequestCreator.GZip);
```